# c++ exception class source code

Tags: exception

Does anyone have a copy of the source code for exception class? 
I would like to study it's implementation.
Thanks
edit: I am looking for std::exception
I am interested in it because I would like to know how the constructor takes a char* and initializes it's member variable, and how the copy constructor, assignment operator is done in this class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no base "exception class" in C++:  you can throw just about anything, even an `int` (`throw 42;` is quite valid).

If you're talking about the `std::exception` class, there is very little in it:  none of its member functions actually need to do anything (`what()` just has to return a pointer to some C string).  The following would be a completely correct implementation:

```
struct exception {
    exception() throw() { }
    exception(const exception&) throw() { }
    exception& operator=(const exception&) throw() { }
    virtual ~exception() throw() { }
    virtual const char* what() const throw() { return "o noez! an exception!"; }
};
```

The exception classes in the Standard Library that allow you to specify your own string (for example, `std::runtime_error`) use `std::string`.  They shouldn't have to do any manual memory management because they can use `std::string`. (Technically, an implementation doesn't have to use `std::string` internally, but it does have to take one in its constructor.)